# Arguments in inherited methods in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, keyword-argument

Suppose we've a parent class A and two child classes, B and C.

```
class A():

  def common_method(arg1):
    # Doesn't use arg1

class B(A):

  def common_method(arg1):
    # Uses arg1

class C(A):

  def common_method(arg1):
    # Doesn't use arg1
```

We want to use the same, "common_method" name in both classes B and C. What's the best way to refactor this in Python?

1. Should we use **kwargs instead of a specific argument name?
2. Should we be adding if/elif wherever we're calling this function to check if the function of that class needs that argument or not?
3. Should we put "arg1 = None" in class C's common method to signify that it's
   not a required parameter?

Comment: Why do you care? Just always pass the argument and let it be ignored, if not needed by the method.

Comment: Will the implementation of `common_method` change from parent to child class? Also, are these `static` methods (no self)?

Comment: The implementation will change for some child classes. These are not static methods, self is being passed.